# Dynamic Links with Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Using Jade + Express + Node.js + Mongoose + MongoDB for my app, but this issue I ran into is likely in Jade:

I have some code as follows that prints a list of posts by title, author

```
div#articles
      -each post in records
         div.article
            #{post.title} was written by #{post.author}
            <a href ="#{post.title}"> Link to Article </a>
```

Now I want to the link in written Jade instead of HTML, but when I replace the  line with

```
a(href='#{post.title}')
```

it links to /#{post.title} instead of the variable name such as /newpost1. Doing it as

```
a(href=#{post.title})
```

returns an error. I'm sure this is a syntax issue, but I can't find the solution in the GitHub documentation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

pretty sure you can just do:

```
a(href=post.title)
```

Comment: Doh I forgot I didn't have to escape from within Jade. Thanks!

Comment: From within a repeat group, the above didn't work for me, but `a(href="{{post.link}}")` did

Answer (score 5):

jade:

```
- var records = [ { title: 'one', author: 'one' }, { title: 'two', author: 'two' } ];
div#articles
  -each post in records
     div.article
        | #{post.title} was written by #{post.author}
        a(href =post.title) Link to Article
```

html:

```
<div id="articles">
  <div class="article">one was written by one<a href="one">Link to Article</a></div>
  <div class="article">two was written by two<a href="two">Link to Article</a></div>
</div>
```